# At some point the sound stop working

Tags: android, button, audio

I have many radiobuttons, each one when selected playing a specific sound.
However, after using different sound and using the app, it stops working (no sound played anymore).

Here is the related code, I extracted the relevant part and it is inside a fragment FYI, pretty standard :

```
final MediaPlayer[] mediaplayarr = new MediaPlayer[10];

TextView tv1 = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.text1);
tv1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View tv1)
    {            
        mediaplayarr[0] = MediaPlayer.create(getActivity(), R.raw.sound1); 
        mediaplayarr[0].start(); 
    }
```

I have googled this issue but nothing seems related. The different buttons (10 as you can see) works fine, same if you want to repeat them, but after a while using them it stops working.

Please let me know if you have any suggestions.

Comment: Do you stop all running sounds (if there is any) when starting a new one? That may cause an issue.

Comment: No I don't. I was thinking also, it would be probably because of this. But if someone click a new radiobutton and there is not sound it could be quite disappointing for the user that is why I would like to enable multiple sounds at the same time.

Comment: Any clue about this situation ?

Comment: So you want's something as a piano so the user would able to play sounds parallely?

Comment: it is in order to play sound according to the radiobutton selected but if the user has to wait the sound to finish playing, it is possible that the user select another button and then the sound doesnt play, which is very misleading and reduce the enjoyment experience. Its for a game like Donkey Kong 3 the cavern of banana birds if you know for your reference ;)

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem myself by putting "mediaplayarr[0] = MediaPlayer.create(getActivity(), R.raw.sound1); " before tv1.setonclicklistener. I hope it can help someone-else.